# function meromorphic on C

Tags: complex-analysis, algebraic-geometry

Good evening I have a doubt:
let $f$ and $g$ are two functions meromorphic on $\mathbb{C}$ such that $g(w) =f(\frac{1}{w})$. Now g is defined for $w = 0$ (because of all meromorphic $\mathbb{C}$).Can i say that $f$ is meromorphic on $\mathbb{C_\infty}=\mathbb{C}\cup\infty$?

Comment: Yes. The relation $g(w) = f(1/w)$ together with the assumption that $g$ is meromorphic in a neighbourhood of $0$ gives the meromorphicity of $f$ in a neighbourhood of $\infty$, since $f$ was assumed to be meromorphic on $\mathbb{C}$, that yields the meromorphicity on the entire sphere. (And that means $f$ is a rational function.)

Comment: and if instead $g(w)=\frac{1}{w^2}f(\frac{1}{w})$ does it continue to hold?

Comment: Yes. If $g$ is meromorphic in a neighbourhood of $0$, then so is $w\mapsto w^2g(w)$, and $w^2g(w) = f(1/w)$ then yields the meromorphicity of $f$ in a neighbourhood of $\infty$.

Comment: you suggested that f is rational. can how I show it?

Comment: If it is rational on the entire sphere, can it have infinitely many poles?

Comment: no because of the set of zeros and poles of a meromorphic function is a closed and discreet subset  of $\mathbb{C_\infty}$ so it is finite. so?

Comment: (Mathematically irrelevant but: typo, "discreet" means something quite different from "discrete".) So $f$ has finitely many poles $p_1,\dotsc,p_k$. Let $h_\kappa$ be the principal part of $f$ in $p_\kappa$. Then each $h_\kappa$ is a rational function, and $f - \sum\limits_{\kappa=1}^k h_\kappa$ is holomorphic on the entire sphere. What can you say about a function that is holomorphic on the entire sphere?

Comment: f is a constant.Can I show it in this way: let $p_1,p_2,...,p_n$ the poles with order $m_1,...,m_n$ and let $q_1,...,q_s$ the zeros with order $n_1,...n_s$. I define the polynomial 
$P(z)=\prod_{i=1}^n (z-p_i)^{m_i}$ and $Q(z)=\prod_{j=1}^s (z-q_j)^{n_j}$. Then $H(z)=f(z)\frac{P(z)}{Q(z)}$ is holomorphic on $\mathbb{C_\infty}$ so $H(z)=cost$. Then $f(z)=cost\frac{Q(z)}{P(z)}$. Is it correct?

Comment: If $f$ has a pole or a zero at $\infty$, you have to modify it a bit. But in principle, it works.

Comment: how can I change H?

Comment: Well, obviously a factor $(z-\infty)^{\pm k}$ causes problems for $k\neq 0$. So just leave that aside for the moment, and take only the factors for the zeros and poles in $\mathbb{C}$. What do you get then?

Comment: I did not understand how I can deal with the case $p_i=\infty$ o $q_j=\infty$

Comment: You leave that out. Consider only the zeros and poles in $\mathbb{C}$ for your $P$ and $Q$. Then what can you say about $H(z) = f(z) \frac{P(z)}{Q(z)}$?

Comment: is constant on $\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: Why is it constant? (Or, how do you know that it is?)

Comment: because of Liouville theorem.

Comment: How do you know that you can apply it?

Comment: because H is holomorphic and limitated on $\mathbb{C}$

Comment: How do you know it's bounded?

Comment: because $z=\infty$ is not a pole for f. right?

Comment: Well, it might. We started with the situation that $\infty$ might be a pole of $f$. Why is it not one of $H$?

Comment: if $\infty$ is a pole or a zero of f then $\infty$ is a pole or a zero of H. So does I have to multpily for an appropriated $z^k$?

Comment: is it correct???????

Comment: thinking back to exercise. I can prove the result in this way: 
Let $p_1,p_2,...,p_n$ the FINITE poles of $f$ with order $m_1,...,m_n$ and $q_1,...q_s$ the FINITE zeros of $f$ with order $n_1,..n_s$. Definte the polynomials
$P(z)=\prod_{i=1}^n (z-p_i)^{m_i}$ and $Q(z)=\prod_{j=1}^s (z-q_j)^{n_j}$ 
Let $H(z)=f(z)\frac{P(z)}{Q(z)}$ 
is meromorphic on $\mathbb{C_\infty}$. If $z=\infty$ is a zeros of $H(z)$ is clearly bounded. If $z=\infty$ is a pole of $H$ i consider the function $\frac{1}{H(z)}$ that is bounded then $\frac{1}{H(z)}$ is constant. Then from Liouville theorem H is constant.

Comment: Or: $H$ is an entire holomorphic function that has at most a pole in $\infty$. Hence $H$ is a polynomial. But $H$ has no zero, hence $H$ is constant.

Comment: can you explain better?

Comment: Extended discussion should take place in the chat room instead of in the comment sections to questions. If you want to continue your discussion, I recommend you take it to one of the chat rooms

Answer (score 1):

Let me try to give a rigorous and clear answer to this question.
First of all what is $\mathbb{C}_{\infty}=\mathbb{C}\cup\{\infty \}$ ? It is a Riemann surface, which means that it is covered by open sets each locally homeomorphic to the unit disc or complex plane and such that the change of coordinate functions are analytic.

Now $\mathbb{C}_{\infty}$ can be covered by two open sets, $A=\mathbb{C}$ and $B=(\mathbb{C}\setminus \{0\}) \cup\{\infty \}$

Now the map $\psi:A \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ given by $\psi(z)=z$ is a homeomorphism, and the map $\varphi :B\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ given by $\varphi(z)=\frac{1}{z}$ is also a homeomorphism. Where naturlly we define $\varphi(\infty)=0$.

Now it must be seen that 
$\psi\circ \varphi^{-1}:\mathbb{C}\setminus \{0\} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}\setminus \{0\}$ is analytic. But this map is $\frac{1}{z}$ and its analytic.

OK now what is meant by a analytic function $f:\mathbb{C}_{\infty} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}_{\infty}$ ? It is function such that for every open set $U$ of the domain with homeomorphism $\alpha:U\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$  and open set $V$ of the range 
with homeomorphism $\beta:V \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$, the map 
$\beta \circ f\circ\alpha^{-1}$ is analytic.

Now let us define

$$\tilde{f}(z)=\begin{cases} f(z)& z\in \mathbb{C}\\ 
g(0)& z=\infty\\
\end{cases}$$
  Now on the set $A$, $\tilde{f}$ is a meromorphic function and so this case satisfes the definition.

Now let us examine $B$, then for all finite $z$,
$$\tilde{f}\circ \varphi^{-1}(z)=f(\frac{1}{z})=g(z)$$ and by definition this also 
holds for $z=\infty$.

Now $g(z)$ is also a meromorphic function and again the definitions are fulfilled.

This then proves that  $\tilde{f}$ is a well defined meromorphic function.

Comment: if instead $g(w)=\frac{1}{w^2}f(w)$ how can i define $\widetilde{f}$?

Comment: just replace $g$ by $w^2g$ in the above discussion.

Comment: so it becomes 
$$\tilde{f}(z)=\begin{cases} f(z)& z\in \mathbb{C}\\ 
0& z=\infty\\
\end{cases}$$?

Comment: then in this case $\tilde{f}$ is clearly meromorphic on $\mathbb{C_\infty}$ since $f$ was meromorphic on $\mathbb{C}$ . right?

Comment: But you need the assumption that g is meromorphic

Comment: from the hypotheses i have g meromorphic.